# keyboard not working for login nor via live image usb

Tags: arch-linux, kde, login, keyboard, surface

My keyboard is not working anymore for login in KDE Plasma - Arch Linux on my Microsoft Surface Pro 4. I did not delete software.

**I tried**
booting using the live image used for installation, so I can reinstall some software (which I do not know yet), but as my keyboard is also not working after booting using the live image, I cannot type any command.

There is a virtual keyboard at the start, but disappears when using the live image used for installation.

**What can I do when I cannot type commands?**

Thank you in advance,

Roberto
PS I regularly update the softwares

Answer (score 0):

I let check my Microsoft Surface Pro 4 laptop, and they told me the problem was an update and Surface has its own specific drivers. So, I bought a new laptop which is more compatible with Arch Linux: Dell XPS 9343.
Cheers, Roberto